# Testes de integração usando sqlite memory duas chamadas api

Tags: c#, testes, asp.net-core

Estou com problemas ao fazer uma chamada de insert (e criação do banco) depois de consulta ocorre que o banco de dados é em memoria o problema é que acada chamada o banco morre.
Seria interessante eu poder fazer a criação do banco de dados no meu teste e manipular ele.

```
// Act
var model = new CreateOrUpdateTagsModel
{
    UserId = 1,
    CatalogItemType = "Movie",
    Owner = 1,
    PinRequired = false,
    ProductId = 1,
    TagType = "Stars",
    TagValue = "5"
};

var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, jsonSerializerSettings);

var response2 = await _client.PutAsync("/v1/tags", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
response2.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

var responseString2 = await response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var response = await _client.GetAsync("/v1/tags?userId=1");
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

Comment: Aparentemente você está testando chamadas a apis. Neste caso seria melhor você focar os testes na sua lógica e utilizar mocks para simular essas chamadas sem que elas sejam feitas de fato. Com esta dependência você precisa garantir que o ambiente com a api esteja disponível ao executar os testes, o que pode ser muito ruim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver mudando minha StartupTest.cs para o `IDbConnection` usar `AddSingleton` e no meu teste usando `_queryExecutor = _server.Host.Services.GetService(typeof(IQueryExecutor)) as IQueryExecutor;` sendo `_server` instancia de `TestServer`.